# docker-machine:Error with pre-create check: "exit status 126"

Tags: macos, docker, docker-machine

When I'm type the code `sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default` to create a new virtual machine. It can not worked. Here is the info:

```
xxxMacBook-Pro:~ xxx$ docker --version
Docker version 1.12.0, build 8eab29e
xxxMacBook-Pro:~ xxx$ docker-machine --version
docker-machine version 0.8.0, build b85aac1
xxxMacBook-Pro:~ xxx$ sudo docker-machine create --driver virtualbox default
Running pre-create checks...
Error with pre-create check: "exit status 126"
```

Please help me to figure this out.

Answer (score 12):

Exit status 126 on a Mac indicates that you don't have Virtualbox installed, which comes separate from Docker.

Run the following command to install it:

```
brew cask install virtualbox;
```

Now you can gracefully run your command again.

NB: You don't have to use `sudo`, unless there are some special privileges you want to accord whatever you are creating.

**Update**: As of 2021 you can use

```
brew install --cask virtualbox
```

Answer (score 0):

The same error occurred on my OSX, because I'v only installed docker.app.
Probably, you should install docker toolbox instead of docker.app.

Docker.app doesn't include virtualbox driver, but docker toolbox includes virtual box driver.

https://www.docker.com/products/docker-toolbox

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Docker for Mac. You need to install VirtualBox additionally from https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads